# Having trouble understanding multiple awaits in async functions

Tags: javascript, async-await

I wrote this function to generate png files from some svg files across a few directories.  I was doing the below functionality synchronously and it was working as expected (same code as below but with readFileSync), but was told to re-do it to use only promisified fs functions.

The current code skips a couple files in both groupA and groupB, plus its swapping widths.  For example, I've noticed the conversion function wont generate for `svg1` of `dirB`, but will generate for `svg1` of `dirA` though it has incorrect width that matches `svg1` of `dirB`.

Most files convert correctly, but a handful don't.  My guess is its a timing issue, so how do I fix that while still keeping the fs functionality all promisified?

```
const { createConverter } = require('convert-svg-to-png');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const util = require('util');

const readdir = util.promisify(fs.readdir);
const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);

async function convertSvgFiles(dirPath) {
  const converter = createConverter();

  try {
    const files = await readdir(dirPath);

    for (let file of files) {
      const currentFile = path.join(dirPath, fil);

      const fileContents = await readFile(currentFile);
      const fileWidth = fileContents.toString('utf8').match(\*regex capture viewbox width*\);

      await converter.convertFile(currentFile, { width: fileWidth });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn('Error while converting a file to png', '\n', err);
  } finally {
    await converter.destroy();
  }
}

['dirA', 'dirB', 'dirC'].map(dir => convertSvgFiles(`src/${dir}`));
```

Comment: have you tried using `Promise.all`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks pretty good.  I do not see anything obvious that would cause the behavior you describe - you await each promise within the function.  You are not using global variables.

I'll say that this line:

```
['dirA', 'dirB', 'dirC'].map(dir => convertSvgFiles(`src/${dir}`));
```

ends up running your function on all 3 directories *in parallel*, with 3 converter instances.  Assuming there are no parallel-related bugs in converter, this should not cause any issues.

But just for grins, try changing that to:

```
async function run() {
  for (let d of ['dirA', 'dirB', 'dirC']) {
    await convertSvgFiles(`src/${d}`)
  }
}

run()
```

to force the folders to be scanned sequentially.  If this resolves the issue, then there's a bug within `convert-svg-to-png`.